# HTML and CSS Troubles with Hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm making a website. Yay! So yeah. I have a navigation bar in the top right, but when I try to hover over it, the hover doesn't work, only when I hover in a certain section: right on the top of word. The rest of the links work though.
Here is the Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Blog</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blog.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/22600000/Smiley-Face-smiley-faces-22608094-1000-1000.png">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mmenu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mmenu.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="strawpoll" href="#"> Strawpoll </a></li>
                    <li><a id="previousblogs" href="#"> Previous Blogs </a></li>
                    <li><a id="aboutme" href="#"> About Me </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h1><a href="#">My Life</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Recent Blogs</h2>
            <h3><a href="#">Week 1</a></h3>
            <a href="file:///E:/Week%201/week%201.html"><img style='border:5px solid #FFFFFF' width="400" height="300" src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/YQ9Usfh.jpg"></a>
            <h4>Short Description................................................................................................</h4>
            <h3><a href="#">Week 2</a></h3>
            <img style='border:5px solid #FFFFFF' width="400" height="300" src="http://wallpoper.com/images/00/17/67/51/anime-forest_00176751.jpg">
            <h4>Short Description................................................................................................</h4>
            <h3><a href="#">Week 3</a></h3>
            <img style='border:5px solid #FFFFFF' width="400" height="300" src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/WWFeR4k.jpg">
            <h4>Short Description................................................................................................</h4>
        </div>
        <footer class="container">
            <div class="pictures" >
                <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img width="30" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/twitter.svg"></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img width="30" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/facebook.svg"></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img width="30" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/instagram.svg"></a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#navbar ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    border-left: 5px solid white;
}
.header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header ul li a {
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.header ul li a:hover {
    color: royal-blue;
}
a#strawpoll {
    right: 215px;
}
a#previousblogs {
    right: 95px;
}
a#aboutme {
    right: 15px;
}
h1 {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 15px;
    color: white;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-image: url('https://cms-images.idgesg.net/images/article/2015/11/black-100630491-orig.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h3 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
div .pictures {
    position: relative;
    left: 610px;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: What is that wall of "test" again...? Is it just there to bypass the more-text-needed-for-this-much-code filter?

Comment: Wow, learn to better format a question

Comment: Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As a recommendation, I can see in your CSS, that you are using link selectors as an example as follows: `a#divid`. don't include the a in the beginning of the selector, just write the id.

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't want to post a lot of questions at once. I could split it up. Is that more preferable for this site?

Comment: ok, just learning this site.

Comment: Often, the code itself is fine but the context is wrong. Post a link to your website draft or recreate the problem in an online tool like jsfiddle (Google it!). If by then, you haven't solved it yourself, come back, post the problem, define the expected and actual behaviour and show us what you tried.

Comment: You're making it pretty hard to follow your code, because you made a lot of mistakes and bad practices: put css/js file inclusion where it belongs (in head or at the bottom of body); run your code through validation (there are a lot of loose closing tags); avoid inline css as much as possible; format your code for better readability

Answer (score 0):

I made fiddle from your code (with a few fixes): https://jsfiddle.net/wka034en/1/

The Problem is, that your H1 headline is overlapping your navigation.

Just adding:

```
.header ul li a {
    /* ... */
    z-index: 10;
}
```

... solves your issue with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/wka034en/2/

---

But again, it's far away from good practice.
Why do you position every navigation link seperatly? You could just position the whole list instead: https://jsfiddle.net/wka034en/3/

```
.header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 8px;
}
.header ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

---

Most browsers have developer tools - or you can install add-ons like Firebug. Those tools can be activated by pressing `F12` or via menu. In a few browsers (like Safari) you need to enable Developer-Mode in the settings first.
You can right-click on an element and select something like *"inspect"* from the context menu to let you jump to the correct DOM position in your developer window.
Using those you can pretty fast determine the root of a cause yourself next time.

---

Regarding your other problem with the horizontal scroll bar:

That's because your `H1` is of type block per default. You position it relatively moving it 10px from left. So your whole content takes up place of 100% width plus 10px. That's why a scroll bar is needed. You can either use `overflow-x:hidden` on your body, or just avoid this bad practice of relative positioning an element like that.
Just use margins and paddings instead.

Change your CSS to:

```
h1 {
    /* ... */
    padding-left: 10px;    /* was: 'left: 10px;' */
    /* ... */
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldcjmkn8/

For further guidance, I recommend you to read about resetting CSS: http://cssreset.com/